# Radeon HD4850 card, ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS Installed FGLRX drivers, but still running vesa, how to solve it?

Tags: fglrx

I have an ati HD4850 card, ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.
To begin with, after a fresh install, i installed fglrx drvers from system -- additional drivers, according to fglrxifo everything was alright, but the system was running on vesa:sem.

After that, i have reinstalled and installed drivers according to many tutorials, but still got that problem.
one of the tutorials was here: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

of course, i attempted to install 12.6 driver

Now i have a fresh install of ubuntu and don't want to touch anything without anyone's support, because my 3 days nightmare didn't give results.

what must i do to have an adequate performance of video card?

Thanks in advance.